# Change a JSON value with an MUI Switch component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, material-ui

I am setting the state of an MUI switch based on the response from an API.  The `Active` field in this API response dictates whether the Switch is checked or unchecked.

The switch is checked if the JSON field is `1`, and un-checked if the field is `0`.  When I manually check or un-check the switch, I want to reflect this in JSON by changing the value of `Active` to `1` or `0`.

```
    const [checked, setChecked] = useState(true);
    const [details, setDetails] = useState("");  //This is where my API response is stored

    function ActivityStatusSwitch() {
        if (details.Active === 1) {
            return (
                <FormControlLabel                   
                    control={<Switch checked={checked} onChange={handleSwitchChange} />}
                    label="Active"
                    labelPlacement="start"
                />
            );
        } else
            return (
                <FormControlLabel
                    control={<Switch checked={checked} onChange={handleSwitchChange} />}
                    label="Inactive"
                    labelPlacement="start"
                />
            );
    }

    const handleSwitchChange = (e) => {
        setChecked(e.target.checked);
        setDetails((prev) => {
            return { ...prev, Active: e.target.value };
        });
    };
```

This is a short example of my JSON:

```
{
  "Active": 1
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've always found it easier to use boolean states for situations like this. Since you're already using 1 & 0, that's simply true & false.

Therefore, you can do something like this if your `Active` field is true/false instead:

```
const handleSwitchChange = (e) => {
    setChecked(e.target.checked);
    setDetails((prev) => {
        return { ...prev, Active: !prev.Active };
    });
};
```

If you really insist on using 1 & 0, you can still achieve the same thing with a simple conditional.

```
const handleSwitchChange = (e) => {
    setChecked(e.target.checked);
    setDetails((prev) => {
        return { ...prev, Active: mapActiveValue(prev.Active) };
    });
};

const mapActiveValue = (val) => {
    return val === 0 ? 1 : 0
}
```